# Update Individual records of mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code, shown below. My problem is that currently this allows every record of mysql table to be update. What I want to happen is for the user to click on the update button and that runs a piece of code pulling that record into the original form. So they can only update that one record.

Thanks in advance

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Comic Collectors Club</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" media="screen and (min-width:481px)">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet mobile.css" media="screen and (max-width:480px)">
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">

<div id="header">
<h1>Welcome To The Comic Collectors Club Website</h1>
</div>

<div id="nav">
</body>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="database.html">Add Your Comic To The Database</a></li>
      <li><a href="export.php">View Our Collection</a></li>
      <li><a class="active" href="update.php">Update Our Collection</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="section">

<div id="search">
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="button" value="Search"></input>
</div>

<h1>Update Our Collection</h1>
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'comics');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password1234');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("comics",$link);

if (isset($_POST['update'])){
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE comics SET Email='$_POST[email]', Title='$_POST[Title]', Issue='$_POST[issue]', Edition='$_POST[edition]', Publisher='$_POST[publisher]', Quality='$_POST[quality]' WHERE Email='$_POST[hidden]'";
mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $link);   
};

$sql = "SELECT * FROM comics";
$myData = mysql_query($sql,$link);


echo "<table border=1>
<tr><th>Email</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Issue</th>
    <th>Edition</th>
    <th>Publisher</th>
    <th>Quality</th>
    <th>Cover Image</th></tr>";
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
echo "<form action=update.php method=post>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=email name=email value=" . $record['Email'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=title value=" . $record['Title'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=number name=issue value=" . $record['Issue'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=edition value=" . $record['Edition'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=publisher value=" . $record['Publisher'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=quality value=" . $record['Quality'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $record['Email'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update value=update" . " </td>";
echo "</form>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($link);
?>
<div id="footer">
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#">Company Information</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">Conventions</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">Collections</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">Your Account</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're wide open to an SQL injection here, btw.

Comment: Its for a class project, however, I am open to suggestions to make it more secure. Any learning is good learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to close your input tags, also you dont need hidden input of email since you already have this. Anyway i changed your code as below, try this one:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Comic Collectors Club</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" media="screen and (min-width:481px)">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet mobile.css" media="screen and (max-width:480px)">
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">

    <div id="header">
        <h1>Welcome To The Comic Collectors Club Website</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="nav">
</body>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="database.html">Add Your Comic To The Database</a></li>
    <li><a href="export.php">View Our Collection</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="update.php">Update Our Collection</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="section">

    <div id="search">
        <input type="text"></input>
        <input type="button" value="Search"></input>
    </div>

    <h1>Update Our Collection</h1>
    <?php

    define('DB_NAME', 'comics');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password1234');
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

    if (!$link) {
        die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("comics",$link);

    if (isset($_POST['update'])){
        $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE comics SET Email='".$_POST['email']."', Title='".$_POST['Title']."', Issue='".$_POST['issue']."', Edition='".$_POST['edition']."', Publisher='".$_POST['publisher']."', Quality='".$_POST['quality']."' WHERE Email='".$_POST['email']."'";
        mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $link);
    };

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comics";
    $myData = mysql_query($sql,$link);


    echo "<table border=1>
<tr><th>Email</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Issue</th>
    <th>Edition</th>
    <th>Publisher</th>
    <th>Quality</th>
    <th>Cover Image</th></tr>";
    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
        echo "<form action=update.php method=post>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=email name=email value='" . $record['Email'] . "'></td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=title value='" . $record['Title'] . "'> </td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=number name=issue value='" . $record['Issue'] . "'> </td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=edition value='" . $record['Edition'] . "'> </td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=publisher value='" . $record['Publisher'] . "'> </td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=quality value='" . $record['Quality'] . "'> </td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value='" . $record['Email'] . "'> </td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update value='update'></td>";
        echo "</form>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysql_close($link);
    ?>
    <div id="footer">
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#">Company Information</a></td>
                <td><a href="#">Conventions</a></td>
                <td><a href="#">Collections</a></td>
                <td><a href="#">Your Account</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for that but, how do I edit the code so update takes you to a new page so you can only update that individual record?

Answer (score 0):

First, complete the input tags with `\>`, maybe the problem happens because that.

**I have a couple solutions that maybe working:**

- Try to change the name of the input `hidden`.
- Try to organize the rows in the table `comics` by id. Then, in the where condition, select rows by their id.
- I think you have to add an input that gives id parameter.
  Select your rows to update by this id with where condition.